# How to authenticate corporate users with Azure AD, and also external users in a single page application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have single page app (Angular front end and .NET Core Web API) using Azure AD for authentication. Both front end and and Web API are registered in the same tenant and WebUI has permissions to call the Web API. This Web API uses a few other internal Web API's as well.

We have a new requirement in the app to allow access to certain areas of the app to external users who need to register first. So now the app need to authenticate both existing AD Users plus external users.

My question is if this is possible in a single application? And if yes what is the recommended approach for authenticating both corporate and external users?

Comment: Hi Rumi, are you using custom policies or flows?

Comment: Ermm its standard Azure Ad integration and the UI app is using implicit grant flow. I have not started using B2C but can consider using it if that could help us authenticate both corporate Ad users and external users using any custom policies

Comment: External users should be stored in a B2C unless there is a good reason to store it in B2B. What we use is a B2C policy with Azure AD as an added IDP. When the user gets to the sign-in page they have the option to sign in with their normal account or there is a button to login using Azure Ad. Another method we use is a Home Realm Discovery page in B2C that detects AD account and redirects them.

Comment: Can you possibly provide a link where I can find a bit more adding b2c policy with azure ad? thanks

Comment: Sure, here is a link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant You are also welcome to message me about your questions.

Comment: I guess we have to migrate all existing app registrations (i.e WebUI and Web API's consumed) in this new tenent of b2c? or we migrate the main WebUI app and leave the Web API's in the existing tenenat. If we keep the WebAPI's in the existing tenant then can we consume the WebAPI's cross tenenats i.e from B2C to Azure AD tenenat? thanks

Comment: You keep the Web Apps in the current tenant/subscription. You create new App Registrations in the AAD B2C tenant. You reconfigure the Apps to trust the B2C tenant authority and token issuer.

Comment: @JasSuri can you kindly give me a bit more info, a link or a blog with a bit more detail on this? As this seems like an ideal solution to keep web apps and api's in the exisitng tenant

Answer (score 2):

As you need to use register feature, you will need to use Azure AD B2C, and it supports multi providers for a valid user flow.

For example, if you want azure ad users and external users to use your application. You can choose OpenID Connect(Azure AD) and Local Account(or other social accounts). In the login page, users can choose to sign up or use Azure AD account to login directly.

[image]

**Steps:**

Just keep your Wep Apps and api apps in the existing tenant. You need to create a Azure AD B2C tenant, create a user sign up/in flow, configure the providers for the user flow.

Reference:

[Create B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant)

[Create user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows)

[Add identity providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-add-identity-providers)

[Configure your original Azure AD application to the identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect)

Comment: This is helpful and apologies for late response. What you are saying is to `keep` the existing web apps and api apps in the same tenant but then you are also saying move/configure the original existing web app into the new b2c tenant and add ad as identity provider? Does that not mean migrate the web app into the new tenant

Comment: @rumi I said 'Just keep your Wep Apps and api apps in the existing tenant. You need to create a Azure AD B2C tenant, create a user sign up/in flow, configure the providers for the user flow.' There is no need to move/configure the original existing webapp into the new tenant.

Comment: I have created a new b2c tenant and configured user signup/sign in flows and configured an open Id Connect provider to use Azure Ad but now how shall I configure my existing app in the existing tenant to use this new tenant for authentication? Can you kindly share another link or tutorial explaining this in a bit more detail?